# How to run Comet with Zinc (Seaside)

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I'm trying to run `Comet` examples from `Seaside 3.0.7 developer image`, but it depends on  `WAListenerAdaptor`, which is not included in this distribution. I could just load `Seaside-Adaptors-Comanche`  (I did in fact) and run off Comanche, but I'm sure the change to Zinc as a default server was done for a reason. I tried to google, but only found this: http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/pharo-project/2012-April/063108.html, which is at best inconclusive.  So the question remains:

- what is a proper way of running `Comet` in this particular configuration (which is an unmodified, official stable one)

NB, This problem is also noted here in comments: 
http://book.seaside.st/book/web-20/comet/getting-started - if I get any conclusive answers I will re-post it there for future readers reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Comet only works with Comanche in Pharo at the moment. This is not something that is not possible with Zinc, just nobody implemented the necessary Zinc adaptor yet.

Comment: Is this still true in 2018?